# SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'employee_id' doesn't have a default value in LARAVEL

Tags: php, laravel

**in blade.php**

```
<select class="form-control" name="selectemployee">
      <option value="">Select One</option>
      @foreach ($employee as $employee)
      <option value="{{ $employee->id }}"> {{ $employee->first_name }}</option>
      @endforeach  
 </select>
```

**here is my controller**

```
    public function store(Request $request)
    { 
        $input = $request->all();      
        Allowance::create($input);     
        return redirect()->route('allowances.index')
                        ->with('success','allowances created successfully.');
    }
```

**this is my error message**
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'employee_id' doesn't have a default value
insert into `allowances` (`year`, `month`, `amount`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (?, ?, ?, 2022-05-21 16:16:44, 2022-05-21 16:16:44)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

```
you may be don't sent employee_id from input
```

you have two choose

1. created  migration file change employee_id to nullable or
2. public function store(Request $request)
   {

   ```
         $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
           'employee_id'  => 'required',
       ]);


       if ($validator->fails()) {
                  return redirect()->route('allowances.index')
                   ->with('errors','allowances created error.');
       }



   $input = $request->all();      
   Allowance::create($input);     
   return redirect()->route('allowances.index')
                   ->with('success','allowances created successfully.');
   ```

   }

Comment: it shoult be not null.
I send employeed_id from input.
when I code like this
`$selectemployee = $request->get('selectemployee');
        dd($selectemployee);
`
result is ^ "1"